# How to pass data from activity to java class in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to pass data from activity to java class in android studio ?

Comment: Without more details it is unlikely that anyone can give a concrete enough answer. Can you share a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: Sorry it is my first time posting a question hehe ill make it clear next time, regarding to my question, ill already found a solution using global variable , sorry for my grammar , i was currently learning on communicating english language hehe